# Batch job sporadically does not get rescheduled

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I have a batch process that I've got scheduled to run after hour (want to increase it to every 15 minutes) and it is currently working 90% of the time just fine, but about once a week is does not get correctly rescheduled for an hour or even sometimes for a full day. There doesn't seem to be a pattern of when it happens and I haven't been able to replicate the issue when testing.

Here is the code:

```
global class OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler implements Schedulable {

Boolean cacheLoaded = false;

private BusinessHours getDefaultBusinessHours() {
    BusinessHours bh = new BusinessHours();
    if(cacheLoaded) return bh;
    bh = [SELECT Id FROM BusinessHours WHERE IsDefault=true];
    cacheLoaded = true;
    return bh;
}

global static String scheduleIt() {
    datetime nextScheduleTime = system.now().addHours(1);
    string minute = string.valueOf(nextScheduleTime.minute());
    string second = string.valueOf(nextScheduleTime.second ());
    string hour = string.valueOf(nextScheduleTime.hour());
    string cronvalue = second + ' ' + minute + ' ' + hour + ' * * ? *';
    string jobName = 'Rescheduling Order Approval Reset Approval Deadline ' + nextScheduleTime.format('hh:mm');

    OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler scheduler = new OrderApprovalDeadlineScheduler();
    return system.schedule(jobName, cronvalue, scheduler);
}

global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {

    BusinessHours bh = getDefaultBusinessHours();
    Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c> recordsToUpdate = new Map<Id, Order_Approvals__c>();
    for(Order_Approvals__c oa : [select Approval_Deadline__c, Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c from Order_Approvals__c where Response__c = NULL]) {
        if(system.now() >= oa.Approval_Deadline__c) {   
            oa.Approval_Deadline__c = BusinessHours.add(bh.Id, oa.Approval_Deadline__c, 32400000);
            oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c = oa.Approval_Deadlines_Missed__c + 1;
            recordsToUpdate.put(oa.Id, oa);
        }
    }
    if(!recordsToUpdate.isEmpty() && recordsToUpdate.size() > 0) {
        update recordsToUpdate.values();
    }
    system.abortJob(sc.getTriggerId());
    scheduleIt();

}
```

}

Does anything in this code jump out that could be causing this issue to happen?

Thanks.

Comment: Some debugging ideas (1) replace system.now() with a `Util.getNow()` method that returns system.now() unless static variable set by `Util.setNow()` is non null. This allows your testmethods to simulate various values of System.now() versus mocked Order_Approvals__c; (2) Introduce persistent Log__c records that you write on each schedule so you can trace what is happening after-the-fact

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered the same issue.   What's happeining is the chronJob object is locked.   I have not found a solution myself, but everytime it encounters the lock error, it automatically set it to run 24 hours later and retry...

Here's the error I see in my org:

> First error: Job object is locked and currently processing.

You can view what's happening during each recent run of a job by going to Setup> Apex Jobs

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue while trying to have a job aborting/scheduling itself every minute (although working fine 99% of the time it randomly failed and schedule itself to run after 24 hours as mentioned in the other answer by James).

As a workaround you can make use of the [Transaction Finalizers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_transaction_finalizers.htm), by **attaching a finalizer within your Queueable job execute method** and performing the abort/scheduling inside the Finalizer execute method in case the Queueable job failed to process. Below is a snippet of how I implemented it:

```
public without sharing class ApexQueueableFinalizer implements Finalizer, Queueable {

    public Integer reschedulingIntervalMinutes;
    public static final String JOB_NAME = 'Apex Queueable Finalizer Job';

    public ApexQueueableFinalizer(Integer reschedulingIntervalMinutes) {
        this.reschedulingIntervalMinutes = reschedulingIntervalMinutes;
    }

    public void execute(System.QueueableContext context) {
        System.attachFinalizer(new ApexQueueableFinalizer(reschedulingIntervalMinutes));
        doThings();
        rescheduleJob();
    }

    public void execute(FinalizerContext ctx) {
        if (ctx.getResult() != ParentJobResult.SUCCESS) {
            rescheduleJob();
        }
    }

    private void doThings() {}

    /**
     * Abort and re-schedule a job given the provided JOB_NAME.
     * With this mechanism we no do not need multiple schedulers for the same job to be executed within minutes.
     */
    private void rescheduleJob() {

        /** 
         * Performs a System.abort() for the current job and schedules the Queueable class again with the same name. 
         * This is where the Job object is locked and currently processing exception might be triggered.
         */

        DynamicSchedulingHelper.abortScheduledJobs(new Set < String > {
            JOB_NAME
        });
        System.schedule(
            JOB_NAME,
            DynamicSchedulingHelper.generateCronExpression(reschedulingIntervalMinutes),
            new ApexQueueableFinalizer(reschedulingIntervalMinutes));
    }
}
```

This way, although we still get the *random* locking errors the Finalizer takes care of the rescheduling retry instead of having to wait the standard 24 hours.